# Fatsecret.com REST API connect with oAuth 1.0 android java

Tags: android, api, rest, oauth, retrofit

I would like to connect fatsecret.com REST api, with Retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/, but I have no any idea, how to set oAuth 1.0 authentication to Retrofit.

The fatsecret.com authentication http://platform.fatsecret.com/api/Default.aspx?screen=rapiauth. Retrofit has any solution this problem? Or any library?